# Code not executing after a for loop with if and else clauses inside

Tags: python, for-loop, execution

Tried to look for other similar questions but couldn't so here we go.

I'm building a desktop app using a GUI library on python called tkinter. The following is one of the functions inside the code that loads a complete frame (which is kind of like a page of the app) after a button is pressed. It just takes a tuple called pom and (with the for loop) displays the information in it on the frame, while it allows user to edit a few values on it through input entries.

I wanted to make a save button that would call an outside function giving it the new edited tuple so I could go on with execution but for some reason I'm not able to make any code after the for loop work.

I wanted to know why. I'm already one hour in and would keep trying until find out what the hell with this thing. Thank you in advance.

```
 def edit_pom(pom):
    #Edit frame set up.
    editFrame.tkraise()
    IdLabel = tk.Label(editFrame, text=str("Editing "+str(pom[-1])), bg=FRAME_BG_COLOR, font=(FONT, 28), fg="white")
    IdLabel.place(relx=1/2, rely=1/45, relwidth=1, anchor="n")

    dataFrame = tk.Frame(editFrame, bg=FRAME_BG_COLOR)
    dataFrame.place(relx=1/2, rely=(1/20)+(1/6), width=WIDTH, relheight=1/2, anchor="n")

    titles = ["dummy","Time","Date","Description","Code","Minutes"]
    entries = []


    index = 1
    for i in pom:
        label1 = tk.Label(dataFrame, text=titles[index]+":", bg=FRAME_BG_COLOR, font=(FONT, 18), fg="white")
        label1.grid(row=index, column=0, sticky="W")

        if titles[index] == "Code" or titles[index] == "Description":
            Entry1 = tk.Entry(dataFrame)
            Entry1.grid(row=index, column=1, sticky="E")
            Entry1.insert(0, i)
            entries.append(Entry1)

        else:
            label2 = tk.Label(dataFrame, text=i, bg=FRAME_BG_COLOR, font=(FONT, 18), fg="white")
            label2.grid(row=index, column=1, sticky="E")

            label1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=10)
            label2.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=10)
        
        index += 1

    print("This part is not being printed.")
```

Comment: Is your program just stuck? I suspect something in your for loop is not returning or failing silently. How about some more granular print statements? Without a block of code to run I can only speculate

Comment: I thought about the silently failing also but it doesn't make sense for it to, I put a print statement at the bottom of the for loop and it does all the iterations it is supposted to and on screen displays eveything it is supposted too. I also tried to comment in the for loop and the code below worked. It's really confusing and literally acts as if whatever I write under the foor loop doesn't exist.

Comment: not at the bottom of the for, but a print inside the bottom of the if and else as well. Also when you say *bottom* of the for,what do you mean? Inside or outside?

Comment: I meant inside the bottom of the for. And I also made two at bottom of if and else and behaved as spected. But I think I finally solved it. Did you noticed the "index" variable? after the for is finished it's supposted to be 5 so I added an if with that condition and a break statement inside and finally the executing kept going (the code at the bottom of the function and outside the for worked).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the for loop is behaving this way. My best guess is that it has to do with the inner functioning of tkinter's mainloop.

In anyway the solution was to **manually break** the for cicle:

```
index = 0
for i in pom:
    if index == 5:
        break

    label1 = tk.Label(dataFrame, text=titles[index]+":", bg=FRAME_BG_COLOR, font=(FONT, 18), fg="white")
    label1.grid(row=index, column=0, sticky="W")

    if titles[index] == "Code" or titles[index] == "Description":
        pass

    else:
        label2 = tk.Label(dataFrame, text=i, bg=FRAME_BG_COLOR, font=(FONT, 18), fg="white")
        label2.grid(row=index, column=1, sticky="E")

    index += 1
```